# Core Bluetooth, how to determine staleness of detection?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Using Core Bluetooth's [CBCentralManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager), one can scan for devices using `scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID]?, options: [String : Any]? = nil)`. I can check for devices thanks to the callback `centralManager(CBCentralManager, didDiscover: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi: NSNumber)`.

Implementing the callback `func centralManager(CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?)` allows one to detect peripherals disconnecting (unpairing). However, how does one detect an unpaired peripheral which goes down (or moves away) without re-scanning?

Do I need to scan periodically and keep a delta of paired devices?

Do BLE peripherals send a message out when they turn off to warn monitoring devices, or should I assume that a device that is not sending advertising packets is asleep/dead/gone? Does the advertising process follow clear rules I can rely on, or does it depends on the device's manufacturer/firmware writer?

Comment: What do you mean by "goes down?" In particular, you'll need to know the advertising behavior of the peripheral. There's no universal answer here. It depends on how the peripheral behaves, and what you're trying to do with that information. Disconnecting from the peripheral at the CBCentralManager layer isn't the same as unpairing. (It may not even be the same as disconnecting from the iPhone.)

Comment: Well, I have a set of sensors which may or may not be broadcasting (they go to sleep after a set delay if not moved around or paired). I want to only show to my user the peripherals that are currently active.

Comment: When you say "broadcasting" you mean sending advertising packets? Do you connect to them, or only monitor their advertising? (I'm assuming these are not iBeacons.) Does anything else connect to them (connecting generally causes a device to stop advertising.)

Comment: The application has code (which I did not write) that scans for the devices, and if the user taps the devices once they display, then the application pairs with the devices. They're not iBeacons, they're Nordic Nrf-based devices, designed to interact with our app over Bluetooth BLE, in particular via MIDI.

Comment: Great. And then what do you want to happen? Do you disconnect at some point? Does the device begin advertising again at that point?

Comment: The app stops scanning only if I leave that screen, and it keeps the peripherals paired unless I refresh (based on what I tested and read from the code). What I'd like to figure out is if I should remove peripherals if they "disappear" as currently, they're stored in an array observable (it's RxSwift which I'm not understanding very well either yet) and only removed the user triggers a manual refresh, force-disconnecting all paired devices, which is problematic, but I'm not understanding how it all works. I want to avoid "blinking" devices (that I remove because they did not advertise yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is somewhat complicated.....

For the most part, if you're connected you know the device is around somewhere. (This isn't 100% true, but close enough usually.) So that should go on the list.

It's possible for the phone to be connected, but not your app. In that case the device won't be advertising so you won't see it. You can check that list by calling `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)`.

And then there's advertising and scanning. The default configuration will only return you an advertising device a single time. If you clear it from your list, it won't be discovered again. What you probably want is `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` (this is an option for `scanForPeripherals(withServices:)`. That will get you a "discovered" call back every time the system sees an advertising packet. You can then keep track of the last time you saw a device and clear out ones you haven't seen in "long enough."

You can also just blindly connect to devices (even devices that aren't currently around), and you'll get a callback when it finally succeeds. This is actually a pretty common technique (it's the one I use most often). It can even be used when the app is in the background; you'll be launched when the device comes in range.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very comprehensive and clear answer (as all of your answers are!) I understand how to modify this now :)